# Сканирование WIA (Метод или операция не реализована.)

Tags: c#, wia

Исключение `Метод или операция не реализована.` возникает на строчке 2 после выбора устройства. Не пойму в чём причина.

```
  try
  {
    DeviceManager DeviceManager1 = new DeviceManagerClass();
    CommonDialog CommonDialog1 = new CommonDialogClass();
    // 1. Помогаем пользователю выбрать устройство
    Device Device1 = CommonDialog1.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, true, false);
    // 2. Делаем снимок
    Device1.ExecuteCommand(CommandID.wiaCommandTakePicture);
    // 3. Снова подключаемся к устройству для получения фото
    Device Device1a = null;
    foreach (DeviceInfo dev_item in DeviceManager1.DeviceInfos)
    {
      // Перечисляем все устройства
      if (dev_item.DeviceID == Device1.DeviceID)
      {
        // и подключаемся к тому, чей DeviceID совпадает с ранее выбранным
        Device1a = dev_item.Connect();
        break;
      }
    }
    // 4. Находим какой объект нам нужен
    Item newItem = Device1a.Items[Device1a.Items.Count];
    // 5. Читаем файл из устройства
    ImageFile newImage = (ImageFile)CommonDialog1.ShowTransfer(newItem, "{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}", false);//FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG
    // 6. Преобразуем полученные данные в вектор
    WIA.Vector newVector = newImage.FileData;
    // 7. Забираем из вектора байтовый массив, содержащий изображение
    Byte[] bytBLOBData = (Byte[])newVector.get_BinaryData();
    // 8. Преобразуем массив в поток
    MemoryStream stmBLOBData = new MemoryStream(bytBLOBData);
    stmBLOBData.Position = 0;
    // 9. Преобразуем поток в изображение 
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(stmBLOBData);
    /*Далее работаем с картинкой*/
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
  }
```